# I'm using Azure Login my website can't login

Tags: reactjs

interaction_in_progress Interaction is currently in progress. Please ensure that this interaction has been completed before calling an interactive API.  For more visit: aka.ms/msaljs/browser-errors."
stack: BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress: Interaction is currently in progress

```
  async login() {

    try {
        await this.PublicClientApplication.loginPopup(
            {
                scopes: "user_read",
                prompt: "select_account"
            });
        this.setState({ isAuthendaicated: true })
    }
    catch (err) {
        this.setState({
            isAuthendaicated: false,
            user: {},
            err: "error"
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not believe you are using `PublicClientApplication` correctly. If you are using plain javascript then you will want to look at the code example at [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-auth-code). The login should look more like `const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to check that no other interaction is in progress before invoking.

```
if (!isAuthenticated && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
  await this.PublicClientApplication.loginPopup({...});
}
```

ref: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/errors.md#browserautherrors